# MVC 5 ActionLink default area value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I've added an area to an existing project and now have the following link to navigate to it:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Dashboard", "Index", "Dashboard", new { area = "Admin" }, null)
```

All the other links in the navigation panel are unchanged and look like:

```
@Html.ActionLink("My Properties", "Index", "Property")
```

The problem is that now when I navigate to the Dashboard and the old links try to navigate me inside that area, the work around I have is:

```
@Html.ActionLink("My Properties", "Index", "Property", new { area = "" }, null)
```

Is there any other way to have a default empty area to existing links? it's a little annoying to chase down all the links and update them

Answer (score 2):

Setting default area in your RouteConfig.cs should help:

You could do it like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
).DataTokens.Add("area", "");
```

or with slightly different syntax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
).DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary(new { area = "" });
```

Comment: This does not work, as when I am in the area the action_link code will try to match with the generic route in the area/RouteConfig

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not a straightforward one. You need to update the links. You can create custom ActionLink extension method Html.DefaultActionLink or something like that and use it to add an empty area (with global replace of all links), if you do not want to write the string in every action.

Comment: check out @user2771704 look like a valid answer